# Neo4j: How do you rebuild the label scan store?

Tags: database, neo4j, lucene, rebuild

I shut down my Neo4J instance every night to do a backup. This morning I found that it failed to start up again:

`2015-12-05 03:38:49.326+0000 INFO  Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server
2015-12-05 03:38:49.330+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7728902c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7728902c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7728902c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:234)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.start(CommunityBootstrapper.java:48)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.main(CommunityBootstrapper.java:35)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7728902c' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:194)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /lustre/scratch116/vr/vrpipe/neo4j/production/db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer$1.newGraphDatabase(CommunityNeoServer.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore@28c94a12' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:66)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:102)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:600)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Label scan store could not be read, and needs to be rebuilt. To trigger a rebuild, ensure the database is stopped, delete the files in '/lustre/scratch116/vr/vrpipe/neo4j/production/db/schema/label/lucene', and then start the database again.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.init(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:259)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:424)
    ... 19 more`

I followed its advice to delete db/schema/label/lucene/*, and the database started up fine, but I can't query any existing nodes or relationships. The web front end says I have no node labels or relationship types. I tried doing `match (n)-[r]-() return n,r`, but that returns nothing.

How do I get my database back? Perhaps I need to force rebuilding of the lucene indexes somehow?

Answer (score 0):

- You took a backup before you deleted it?
- You only deleted that directory?
- What does the new startup log look like?
- How much data do you have in your db?
- What does this return? `match (n) return count(*)`